# Filter joined rows if column's value exists in another table

Tags: mysql, left-join

Today I have encountered a problem as follows (fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b5cff7fb81fbe0ddd077a67629c56b05)):

```
create table ta02 
(
  t_key      varchar(255) default null,
  ta_over_amount decimal(13,2) default null,
  name           varchar(255) default null
);
```

and:

```
create table voucher 
(
  v_key       varchar(255) default null,
  over_amount decimal(13,2) default null,
  signature   varchar(255) default null
);
```

Populate:

```
INSERT INTO ta02 (t_key, ta_over_amount, name) VALUES ('gogo', 100.00, 'anh');
INSERT INTO ta02 (t_key, ta_over_amount, name) VALUES ('gogo', 50.00, 'duc');
INSERT INTO ta02 (t_key, ta_over_amount, name) VALUES ('logbasex', 25.00, 'ho');
INSERT INTO ta02 (t_key, ta_over_amount, name) VALUES ('logbasex', 15.00, 'phi');
```

and:

```
INSERT INTO voucher (v_key, over_amount, signature) VALUES ('gogo', 100.00, 'blue');
INSERT INTO voucher (v_key, over_amount, signature) VALUES ('gogo', 50.00, 'white');
INSERT INTO voucher (v_key, over_amount, signature) VALUES ('logbasex', 14.00, 'itsme');
INSERT INTO voucher (v_key, over_amount, signature) VALUES ('logbasex', 25.00, 'green');
```

This is my join query without any conditions:

```
select t.name, t.ta_over_amount, v.over_amount, v.signature 
from ta02 t 
left join voucher v on t.t_key = v.v_key;
```

Result:

```
name    ta_over_amount  over_amount     signature
anh     100.00           50.00          white
anh     100.00          100.00          blue
duc     50.00            50.00          white
duc     50.00           100.00          blue
ho      25.00            25.00          green
ho      25.00            15.00          itsme
phi     15.00            25.00          green
phi     15.00            15.00          itsme
```

And the required condition is:

- On the same `v_key`, only join which row that has `ta_over_amount` value does not equal to corresponding `over_amount` value of matched row and the list `ta_over_amount` values (get by the joined key `v_key` in `ta02` table) does not contains `over_amount` value, the list `over_amount` values (get by the joined key `v_key` in `voucher` table) does not contains `ta_over_amount` value.
- For example, when joining two tables with `v_key` = `gogo` (first row) in `ta02` table, that will match two corresponding rows in `voucher` table, which is include `signature` = **blue** and **white** respectively. With a row has `signature` = **blue**, the `over_amount` value = 100 is equals to the `ta_over_amount` value then I ignore that row (clearly doesn't satify my condition), with a row has `signature` = **white**, the `over_amount` value = 50 is not equals to `ta_over_amount` but exits in list of `ta_over_amount` values with `v_key` = `gogo` in `ta02` table then I also need to ignore this row.

And this is my desired result:

```
    +----+--------------+-----------+---------+
    |name|ta_over_amount|over_amount|signature|
    +----+--------------+-----------+---------+
    |phi |15.00         |14.00      |itsme    |
    +----+--------------+-----------+---------+
```

- Ex:

```
ta02 table                                
+--------+--------------+----+
|key     |ta_over_amount|name|
+--------+--------------+----+
|gogo    |100.00        |anh |
|gogo    |50.00         |duc |
|logbasex|25.00         |ho  |
|logbasex|15.00         |phi |
+--------+--------------+----+

voucher table
+--------+-----------+---------+
|key     |over_amount|signature|
+--------+-----------+---------+
|gogo    |110.00     |blue     |
|gogo    |50.00      |white    |
|logbasex|25.00      |itsme    |
|logbasex|15.00      |green    |
+--------+-----------+---------+

My expected result is:
+----+--------------+-----------+---------+
|name|ta_over_amount|over_amount|signature|
+----+--------------+-----------+---------+
|anh |100.00        |110.00     |blue     |
+----+--------------+-----------+---------+

- 100 doesn't match 110, I include this one in the desired result.
- 100 doesn't match 50, but 50 exits in ta_over_amount list, ignore
- 50  doesn't match 110, but 50 exits in over_amount list, ignore
- 50 match 50, ignore
```

Comment: Check again the results of your original query. For the sample data you posted the last row should be: `phi 15.00 14.00 itsme` and the 3d from the bottom should be: `ho 25.00 14.00 itsme` and these 2 rows I think should be your expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this sample really represent your complete table? The tables really need a unique key which would make your query so much easier.

As it is one possible way you can get your desired results is with a bit of `not exists` and `not in` using a `cte` for easy reference.

[I've amended your fiddle with a new query that gives your desired output](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=831df624a5aad4829e6e72b347e7b6ca)

```
with t as (
    select *, case when exists (
                select * from voucher v 
                where v.v_key=t.t_key and v.over_amount=t.ta_over_amount)
              then 1 else 0 end excl
    from ta02 t
)
select t.name, t.ta_over_amount, v.over_amount, v.signature
from t join voucher v on v.v_key=t.t_key 
where t.excl=0 and v.over_amount not in (select ta_over_amount from t where excl=1)
```

**Edit**

So the goalposts jumped a little to exclude MySql 8 in favor of 5.7 only, which means `CTE` cannot be used

```
select t.name, t.ta_over_amount, v.over_amount, v.signature
from ta02 t join voucher v on v.v_key=t.t_key 
where not exists (select * from voucher v where v.v_key=t.t_key and v.over_amount=t.ta_over_amount)
    and v.over_amount 
    not in (select ta_over_amount from ta02 t2 where t2.t_key=v.v_key and v.over_amount=t2.ta_over_amount)
```

[Revised Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=03ebe2ecc6ca38a2e091c19fc9be6fc3)

Comment: @logbasex that's great. So what is the issue? I've amended the fiddle demo linked in my answer and edited the data to match the changes you have edited in your question. Running my query, it gives your desired output ie, anh|100.00|110.00 |blue. So if the answer is not correct, you'll need to explain why as it seems to work.

Comment: thanks, but I'm using mysql 5.7. I'm trying to rewrite your answer with this version but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Ah. Ok - maybe that was worth mentioning? ;-)

Comment: I'm not familiar with 5.7 unfortunately but it appears it doesn't support `CTE`s. It's certainly possible to refactor it differently, I will give it some thought when I'm able to.

Comment: I understand your logic but I don't understand  why I'm getting two records with the following code: select t.name, t.ta_over_amount, v.over_amount, v.signature
from (
    select *, case when exists (select * from voucher v where v.`key`=ta02.`key` and v.over_amount=ta02.ta_over_amount) then 1 else 0 end exc
 from ta02
         ) as t join voucher v on v.`key`=t.`key`
where t.exc=0 and v.over_amount not in (select ta_over_amount from t where exc=1);

Comment: @logbasex I've refactored the query I wrote and removed the `CTE` and edited the answer above - [This fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=03ebe2ecc6ca38a2e091c19fc9be6fc3) now has the expected result using v 5.7. Let me know if this successfully answers the question? (ironically this version is slightly more efficient too!)